# get content between custom comment

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a html string. In that I defined some area for editing. That area enclosed in certain comment. I want to get all the content between that comment. For example

```
<!--start--> some content with any html tag <!--end-->
```

In the above example I need the content between the start and end tag. That is want

`some content with any html tag`.

-Arun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = '<!--start--> some content with any html tag <!--end-->';
echo preg_replace('/<!--start--> (.*) <!--end-->/', '$1', $string);
```

Comment: It throws an error. Unknown modifier '<' in E:\wamp\www\test\regu\regan.php. Could you please update your post?

Comment: @user504383: It works for me: http://ich-wars-nicht.ch/regex.php. Are you using php5?

Comment: sorrry danilo, your post was working. hsz code made the error. Sorry once again and thanks for your help,

Comment: see my comment on hsz's answer

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = '<!--start--> some content with any html tag <!--end-->';
preg_match('/<!--start-->(.*?)<!--end-->/', $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Even better, please *don't post* untested answers.  With online testers like [ideone](http://ideone.com/) available, there's no excuse for it.

Comment: The code is not working when there is a lines of contents. for example $string = "head <!--start--> 
some content with any html tag <!--end-->"; Please try this example

Comment: you will probably need the `s` modifier (PCRE_DOTALL) so `preg_match('/<!--start-->(.*?)<!--end-->/s', $string, $matches);` gives the content you want in `$matches[1]`